# Angular 2, Error: Cannot match any routes using named router outlet and [routerLink] inside of named outlet

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, named-routing

I have a minimal Plnkr here: [Named Router Outlet Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/9er5DFDWHCUYuLnIcnuh?p=preview)

This link works outside of the router, but the same link fails if it is inside of a component inside of the named router outlet:

```
<a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { taco: ['al-pastor']} }]">Al Pastor</a>
```

Calling a function on the component that calls the following works:

```
this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { taco: 'al-pastor' }}]);
```

But I would rather use [routerLink]

Is it possible to use [routerLink] to target the current named router outlet?